# 'Slider' does not contain a definition for 'value'

Tags: slider

I want to make some project when I slide the UI slider will appear some text. But after I finish my coding, the error appears.

> error CS1061: 'Slider' does not contain a definition for 'value' and no accessible extension method 'value' accepting a first argument of type 'Slider' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But if I put in a new project, the error did not come out. When I import asset the error comes again.

Here is my code:

```
public class TextControl : MonoBehaviour {

public Slider Food;
public Slider Calories;
public Text States;
public Text Question;

public void Update()
{
    wordShown();
}
public void wordShown()
{
    if (Food.value >= 0.5f) 
    {
        if (Calories.value >= 0.5f) 
        {
            States.text = "INACTIVE, UNHEALTHY";
            Question.text = "What changes can make him be active and healthy?";
        } 
        else if (Calories.value < 0.5f) 
        {
            States.text = "ACTIVE, HEALTHY";
            Question.text = "What should he do to maintaian his fitness?";
        }
    } 
    else if (Food.value < 0.5f) 
    {
        if (Calories.value >= 0.5f) 
        {
            States.text =  "INACTIVE,UNHEALTHY";
            Question.text = "What classes of food should have consume by this person?";
        } 
        else if (Calories.value < 0.5f) 
        {
            States.text =  "ACTIVE, HEALTHY";
            Question.text = "High calorie associated with what type of food?";
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got the solution.
there is actually a script named slider.cs. So I changed it to sliderscript.cs. Slider is the name for the property of unity. we cannot use the property as our script name.

Answer (score 0):

I got another solution.

use UnityEngine.UI.Slider instead of Slider because as Kamil Digital said the property slider and script slider somehow conflict.

Example:

```
Slider MusicSlider; //DOESNT WORK
MusicSlider = musicObj.GetComponent<Slider>();//DOESNT WORK

UnityEngine.UI.Slider MusicSlider;//SHOULD WORK
MusicSlider = musicObj.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Slider>();//SHOULD WORK
```